# What can cause a NotSupportedException when creating an EventWaitHandle?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

## Context

I have a large cross-platform project using [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/). Because I am working pretty much alone on this project and we recently needed the WPF and Windows 10 clients more, I was totally focused on these and I neglected the Android client. (Yeah don't tell me that's bad, I know... :-) )

## The exception

However, now I am working on it again, trying to get it up and running, but I keep getting a `System.NotSupportedException` in a portable class library's code, where a new `EventWaitHandle` is being created.

```
// The next line throws the System.NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported.
new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, module.Identifier.ToString()); // module.Identifier is a GUID (it's valid)
```

This code is some months old and works just fine in the WPF and Windows 10 clients, so I thought perhaps `EventWaitHandle`s are not supported by Xamarin Android, but I could not find any evidence for that. The contrary seems to be case: it is [well documented](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle/).

If it helps (it did not help me much...) here is the complete stack trace of the exception:

```
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): System.NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported.
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00078>
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0006b>
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
11-19 19:18:27.290 I/MonoDroid(26568): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.c26750eb-eb85-45fe-a488-c6d12c1aaf0e (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
11-19 19:18:27.315 W/art     (26568): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable
11-19 19:18:27.320 D/AndroidRuntime(26568): Shutting down VM
An unhandled exception occured.

11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): Process: de.msm.IDS, PID: 26568
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     ... 1 more
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported.
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00078>
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0006b>
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.c26750eb-eb85-45fe-a488-c6d12c1aaf0e (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568): 
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
11-19 19:18:28.190 E/AndroidRuntime(26568):     ... 4 more
```

## Project details

The Android project is set up to use API Level 19:

[image: Android project setup: using API Level 19]

The PCL targets include .NET Framework 4.5 and Xamarin.Android of course:

[image: PCL targets]

The target hardware device I primarily use for debugging is a [Samsung SM-P900](http://www.samsung.com/de/consumer/mobile-devices/tablets/others/SM-P9000ZKADBT) with [Android 5.0.2](https://www.android.com/versions/lollipop-5-0/).

What could possibly cause this exception in Android (but not in Windows)?

Comment: Whats the full stack of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at mono (Xamarin) .NET implementation:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/EventWaitHandle.cs

EventWaitHandle is not supported in mono.

```
public EventWaitHandle (bool initialState, EventResetMode mode, string name)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }
```

Comment: LOL It's that simple? Thanks!

Comment: Would have been nice to mention it in the Xamarin docs, don't you think?

Comment: Yes I agree. There is implementation for mono here: https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/EventWaitHandle.cs
Maybe you can use these.